# filtering string values from an array for formatting only numbers

Tags: php, arrays, number-formatting

The problem is, I have an array that I get from this query :

```
$secimKrm   =   ("SELECT * FROM kurumlar
INNER JOIN veri_2012_09
ON kurumlar.krmKod  =  veri_2012_09.krmKod
WHERE kurumlar.krmKod = '$krmKod'");
$sonucKrm   =   $mysqliKrm->query($secimKrm);
$row    =   $sonucKrm->fetch_assoc();
```

"kurumlar" consists of strings 
and "veri_2012_09" consists of big integers.
There are almost 35 columns in "veri_2012_09" and I don't want to format numbers one by one.

When I try to format numbers in the array "$row" I use this:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
$row[$key] = number_format($val, 0, ',', '.');
}
```

It works, but it causes errors, (*Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in...*) because my array has strings in it. How can I exclude the strings before formatting the numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform [`is_numeric`](http://nz1.php.net/is_numeric) check like:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    if (is_numeric($val)) {
        $row[$key] = number_format($val, 0, ',', '.');
    }
}
```

So your question shouldn't be "How can I exclude the strings", but "How can I include only strings"